# NSData -> NSAttributedString in iOS8

Tags: ios8, nsattributedstring

I believe this is a bug and have submitted a bug report.  Thought I would post here too to see if anyone has any ideas.

On my shipped app, using iOS7, this code works fine.  I create an attributed string with font information, turn it into NSData to store it, then re-load it as an attributed string.

On iOS8, these attributed strings are not loading correctly from NSData, and the font info appears to have been removed.

```
NSMutableAttributedString* string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"this is a test string"];

UIFont* font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"GillSans" size:18];

[string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];

NSLog(@"original attributed string : %@", string);
```

This prints:

> original attributed string : this is a test string{
>       NSFont = " font-family: \"Gill Sans\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 18.00pt"; }

```
NSError* err;

NSData* data = [string dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)
                  documentAttributes:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSRTFTextDocumentType}
                               error:nil];

if(err){
    NSLog(@"error : %@", err);
}

err = nil;

NSAttributedString* newString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:data options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSRTFTextDocumentType} documentAttributes:NULL error:nil];

NSLog(@"new attributed string : %@", newString);

if(err){
    NSLog(@"error : %@", err);
}
```

and then prints:

> new attributed string : this is a test string{
>       NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 0, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0,
>   FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0,
>   LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    28L,\n    56L,\n    84L,\n    112L,\n
>   140L,\n    168L,\n    196L,\n    224L,\n    252L,\n    280L,\n
>   308L,\n    336L\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists
>   (null), BaseWritingDirection -1, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor
>   0, HeaderLevel 0"; }

Comment: Don't throw out the error information. It might just tell you why this is happening.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the example code...  no errors!